# Can external solidity functions get called within the same contract dynamically?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, external-function, dynamic-call

Assume we have the following solidity contract:

```
contract khiar {
    function mooz(uint size) external {
        // do something with mooz!
    }

    function bademjoon(uint size) external {
        // do something with bademjoon and then call mooz
        address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("mooz(uint)", size*2));
    }
}
```

As you can see, `mooz` is an external function, but we need to call it within `bademjoon` function in the same contract dynamically (for whatever reason). Is it a valid call or we need to add `public` modifier to `mooz` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a valid call or we need to add public modifier to mooz ?

It is a valid call, but it's a strange usecase though.

You do not need to add `public` and in fact, you can't. It would trigger a compiler error. See [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#function-visibility) about the function visibility modifers :

> Public functions are part of the contract interface and can be
> either called internally or via message calls.

and

> External functions are part of the contract interface, which means
> they can be called from other contracts and via transactions. An
> external function f cannot be called internally (i.e. f() does not
> work, but this.f() works).

The two are incompatible, public allows internal calls, while external doesn't.